# How to change the cursor pointer on fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar

I'm using fullCalendar plugin for my project. I noticed that when I set the "editable: " into false, the cursor hover on the events becomes default instead of staying as a pointer cursor. How do I change this? Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```css
.myCalendar {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Using the proper css selector instead of `.myCalendar`, of course.
Looking at [this](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) example calendar, you're probably looking for `.fc-event`, to preserve the pointer when hovering over calendar events:

```css
.fc-event{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Add the following CSS.

```
.fc-content {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

`div.fc-content` wraps the calendar cells, so adding `cursor: pointer;` to `.fc-content` will produce the desired behavior.

**But is that really desired?**

In general convention **cursor:pointer** is used for any **clickable element**.

Comment: This works for me, In my case I want the user to be able to click the event which shows a pop up modal, That modal then allows them to manually set the time and date of the event via a select option. Once the finish and hit save, I make a redux call which updates the state in the calendar. I wont want them to drag around events by accident especially on mobile. I found draggable events kind of annoying really

Answer (score 6):

I noticed that if you just set editable to `true` then it will display the finger pointer on hover. I'm not sure why you would even want it to set it to false if you intend to let the user click an event.

So simply set the editable value to `true` during initialization:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  editable: true
});
```

Comment: You may want the user to be able to *click* an event as a link to another page for example, whereas `editable` allows the event to be dragged and moved around the calendar.

Answer (score 4):

In my case simply adding

```
.fc-event{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

to my `scss` class didn't work. It only works when i add `::ng-deep` before it like so:

```
::ng-deep .fc-event{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I hope it helps anyone

Answer (score 0):

For Angular and those who are still struggling:

```
:host ::ng-deep {
    .fc-daygrid{
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}
```

If you want the cursor to be a pointer for the whole calendar, change `.fc-daygrid` to `.fc`.

Answer (score -1):

## Solution for Vue3 with Composition API

```
// Code in template
<full-calendar :options="calendarOptions"></full-calendar>
```

```
// place
export default {
   setup(props) {
       const calendarOptions = {
             plugins: [
                listPlugin,
                dayGridPlugin,
                timeGridPlugin,
                interactionPlugin
            ],
            
            // this is where magic comes in
            editable: true,
       }
   }

   return {
      calendarOptions
   }
}
```

Comment: But this makes the calendar editable, we just want to have the capability to click on event without making them drag-n-dropable