# How do I add cursor pointer on each day ( greater then current day ) block of fullcaledar.

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I need to add cursor on each day that is greater then current date in full calendar.

Comment: What do you mean by "add cursor"?

Comment: I mean to add hand pointer.

Comment: @dekkard I think he means the `cursor` CSS attribute

Comment: you should provide your code , anyways try cursor:pointer; property .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25154084/how-to-change-the-cursor-pointer-on-fullcalendar

Comment: well I add fullcalendar with 'dayClick' event that redirect to my required page. I just want the pointer should be cursor (as mentioned by @Tamis Washtler CSS attribute ). How do I achieve this. I hope you better understand my problem.

Comment: hand pointer already working on hovering any event. but I also want this on every day block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use both css `cursor:pointer` property as well as fullcalendar `dayRender` function follow the code bellow:

**JS**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    dayRender: function(date, cell) {
       if(date.format('YYYY-MM-DD') > $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'getDate' ).format('YYYY-MM-DD')) {
            $(cell).addClass('custom_pointer');
       }
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
.custom_pointer {cursor:pointer;}
```